networksetup -getairportnetwork return You are not associated with an AirPort network
I’m trying to retrieve the name of my Wi-Fi network via the terminal, but I’m encountering some issues.
I tried with the command:
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -s

However, it returns the following warning:
WARNING: The airport command line tool is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
For diagnosing Wi-Fi related issues, use the Wireless Diagnostics app or the wdutil command line tool.

I also tried:
networksetup -getairportnetwork en0

But it returns:
You are not associated with an AirPort network.

Even though I am connected to Wi-Fi. I have tried disconnecting and reconnecting, as well as deleting the following .plist files in /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/:
com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
com.apple.network.identification.plist
com.apple.wifi.message-tracer.plist
NetworkInterfaces.plist
preferences.plist

Despite these efforts, I still have not resolved the issue.
I DON'T want to use wdutil since it requires the sudo password. Is there any way to fix the problem with networksetup, or is there an alternative method to retrieve the Wi-Fi name?
Specifications: macOS Sequoia 15.0 Apple Silicon M3 Pro
UPDATE: Today I reset my mac to the factory settings and the system installed Sonoma as the default OS. I have tried the terminal command networksetup and it works fine. After updating again to Sequoia the problem appears again so I think the problem is directly related to this new update. Unfortunately, I can't find any info about deprecation or warnings on the man.

Please post your solution as an answer below.

@nohillside I haven't found a solution yet

Yep, it's silently gone with Sequoia...

From my limited testing networksetup -listpreferredwirelessnetworks en0 outputs a list of Wifi SSIDs where the first one is the one you're connected to.
Then it would be a matter of formatting the output:
networksetup -listpreferredwirelessnetworks en0 | sed -n '2 p' | tr -d '\t'

I'd like to confirm if this behavior is the same for others as well.
EDIT:
Also works:
ipconfig getsummary en0 | awk -F ' SSID : '  '/ SSID : / {print $2}'

Credit: https://github.com/FelixKratz/SketchyBar/issues/616#issuecomment-2370891970

First, the solution, although it might be a bit slow, will at least provide a result:
system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | awk '/Current Network/ {getline;$1=$1;print $0 | "tr -d ':'";exit}'

refer to this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255761216?sortBy=rank
I tried the following two approaches, but neither worked:
Using AppleScript to call the CoreWLAN API to retrieve the Wi-Fi information:
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "CoreWLAN"
use scripting additions

set wifiInterface to current application's CWInterface's interfaceWithName:"en0"

-- Print the entire object
log wifiInterface



Directly using Swift:

swift -e 'import CoreWLAN; if let wifi = CWWiFiClient.shared().interface()?.ssid() { print(wifi) } else { print("Not connected to any Wi-Fi network") }'


On the off-chance the following proves helpful:
My article Determining a Mac’s SSID (like an animal) describes the following methods to get the Mac’s currently assigned Service Set Identifier (SSID), commonly known as the name of the user’s selected Wi-Fi network:



macOS version
Commands




macOS 15.0 Sequoia
system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | awk '/Current Network Information:/ { getline; print substr($0, 13, (length($0) - 13)); exit }'  /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print :0:_items:0:spairport_airport_interfaces:0:spairport_current_network_information:_name' /dev/stdin <<< "$(system_profiler SPAirPortDataType -xml)" 2> /dev/null


macOS 14.5 Sonoma through 14.7 Sonoma
/usr/sbin/networksetup -getairportnetwork en0 | /usr/bin/awk -F ": " '{ print $2 }'


macOS 14.4 Sonoma and 14.4.1 Sonoma
/usr/bin/wdutil info | /usr/bin/awk '/SSID/ { print $NF }' | head -n 1


macOS 13.6.9 Ventura through 14.3.1 Sonoma
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Resources/airport --getinfo | /usr/bin/awk '/ SSID/{print $NF}'




I assume you are linking to your own website here?

Welcome to Ask Different. This is a really useful answer on how to retrieve SSID information in various versions of macOS. I've edited it to 1) make it clear that it is your website you are linking to (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) 2) add all relevant information inline, as link-only answers are not welcome (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

This finds available SSIDs now when you don't have SSIDs set up:
sudo wdutil info

And this lists SSIDs that you have already set up on your default wifi if en0 is your wifi (as per usual on macOS systems with wifi):
networksetup -listpreferredwirelessnetworks en0

To remove:
networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork en0 "SSID Name"

To add/re-add:
networksetup -addpreferredwirelessnetworkatindex en0 SSID Name" <index_number_priority_preference> <security type> [password]

Seems to have changed around when this posted for using sudo wdutil:
https://old.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/1c4o746/wdutil_replaces_airport_cli_util_but_requires_sudo/
